# What is the header for boost::atomic

Tags: c++, boost, atomic

I want to use `boost::atomic` but what header to include ? there is no `boost/atomic.hpp`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Boost.Atomic` is not an official part of boost as of now. If you still want to use it you need to get it from [here](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/). Alternatively you could try `Boost.Interprocess` for atomic operations, rely on compiler dependent extensions like gccs atomic operations (`__sync_val_compare_and_swap` and such) or, if c++11 is an option use `std::atomic<T>`, which is almost identical to `boost::atomic<T>` IIRC.

**Edit:**
As always these things change: `Boost.Atomic` became an official part of boost with the current 1.53.0 release. It is now availible as `boost/atomic.hpp`.

Answer (score 1):

Boost.Atomic is not yet accepted into boost. There however exists boost/interprocess/detail/atomic.hpp as an implementation detail of Boost.Interprocess.

Comment: but is there any `boost::atomic<>` template there ? I see just `load`, `store` function